# App crashes after reinstall on emulator since FileProvider Class was not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-fileprovider

When I run the app on the emulator it always works on the first try. But when the app is already installed on the emulator it often results in a crash during the start of the app.
This behavior started to occur with Android Studio 2.0.
It does not occur on devices, therefore it is not so important but only annoying since I always need to delete the app from the emulator before installing a new version.

Since I have absolutely no idea what causes this issue and can't find similar issues during research, I hope that somebody can help me.

Error message:

```
08-25 09:55:35.023 4214-4214/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mls.Search.Abbott, PID: 4214
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mls.Search.Abbott-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mls.Search.Abbott-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.mls.Search.Abbott-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mls.Search.Abbott-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mls.Search.Abbott-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.mls.Search.Abbott-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.mls.Search.Abbott/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mls.Search.Abbott-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.mls.Search.Abbott-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
        at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
              ... 12 more
            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.content.FileProvider
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

File Provider in Manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

Comment: hi every one i faced the problem with fileprovider during ionic development  as we use android as a platform with ionic there we build the project using ionic build android so the android.json is also one of the files being read during the build process..i observed that     "/manifest": [] in the android.json generated a wrong line with uses permission tag having the FileProvider class which was throwing the error again and again after nearly 8 to 10 hours of persistant reserach on sttack overflow  and comparing the files with beyond compare i found out this issue..

Comment: I have faced the same problem. but not found any solution

Answer (score 0):

If you use Android 5.0 or lower in your emulator (api level 21),
then  add the multidex support library to your project:

1. If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, all you need to do is set multiDexEnabled to true in your module-level build.gradle file, as shown here:

   ```
   android {
       defaultConfig {
           ...
           minSdkVersion 21 
           targetSdkVersion 26
           multiDexEnabled true
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

   2. if your minSdkVersion is set to 20 or lower, then you must use the multidex support library as follows:

   Modify the module-level build.gradle file to enable multidex and add the multidex library as a dependency, as shown here:

   ```
   android {
       defaultConfig {
           ...
           minSdkVersion 15 
           targetSdkVersion 26
           multiDexEnabled true
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

   dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
   }

Look at
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **`androidx`** libraries, in **`AndroidManifest.xml`**, change this:

```
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
```

to this:

```
android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
```